# How to use the patterns against enum with a default case with param

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I have this enum

```
enum Foo {
    MyFoo(String),
    YourFoo(String),
    HisFoo(String),
    TheirFoo(Vec<String>),
}
```

I would like to apply the same logic to the first 3 variants and a special one to the last one. So I'm trying to do something like this:

```
match foo {
   Foo::TheirFoo(s_vec) => // do something using the vector of strings
   _(s) => // do something else using the string
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish it without specifying every single case?

Comment: What about `OurFoo`???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [or-patterns](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#or-patterns):

```rust
match foo {
   Foo::TheirFoo(s_vec) => { /* do something using the vector of strings */ }
   Foo::MyFoo(s) | Foo::YourFoo(s) | Foo::HisFoo(s) => { /* do something else using the string */ }
}
```

This only works because all three variants bind the same variables with the same types (`s: String`).