# Is there a way to perform same operation on a group of enum variants with SAME inner type?

Tags: rust

Consider a very common use case

```rust
#[derive(Debug, strum::AsRefStr)]
pub enum ClientError {
    FilePathNotExist(String),
    UnableToCreateFile(String),
    UnableToCreateDirectory(String),
    ReceiverNotExist(String),
    CannotEstablishConnection(String),
    AuthenticationFailed,
    ServerDisconnected,
}

impl Display for ClientError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        use ClientError::*;
        let literal = self.as_ref().red();
        let mut info = |info: &str| write!(f, "{literal}: {}", info.yellow());
        match self {
            FilePathNotExist(path) => info(path),
            UnableToCreateFile(path) => info(path),
            UnableToCreateDirectory(path) => info(path),
            ReceiverNotExist(receiver) => info(receiver),
            CannotEstablishConnection(addr) => info(addr),
            _ => write!(f, "{literal}"),
        }
    }
}
```

That is, you have finite possibilities of inner types, in this case they are

```
Self, Self(String), Self(String, String), etc.
```

And for each pattern of inner type, you have a corresponding operation

```
write!(f, "{literal}")
write!(f, "{literal} : {}", arg1)
write!(f, "{literal} : {}, {}", arg1, arg2)
```

Assume the least knowledge of macros, what could be the most elegant way to eliminate duplicated match arms?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74891591/how-to-use-the-patterns-against-enum-with-a-default-case-with-param as it is about handling multiple variants with the same inner value, whereas this question is abouthandling all inner values of the type T, even in Enum::Variant(A, T, B, T)

Comment: @IvanC think again this is about handling the same types of inner parameters with the same match arm, just like the other question.